# Error On Sending Email From Google App Script

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm trying to send an email to a user form after the submit the form. But I got an error:

> Uncaught  at emailCode2 at processForm2

Is there anything I did wrong? Your respond would be appreciated.

Here's my .html code:

```
<script>    
function handleFormSubmit(formObject) {
        google.script.run.processForm2(formObject);
        document.getElementById("myForm").reset();
        alert("Your form is submitted. Thank you!");
      }
</script>
```

Here's my .gs code:

```
function processForm2(formObject) {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var ws = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1");
  var tz = ss.getSpreadsheetTimeZone();
  var d = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), tz, 'dd/MM/yyyy @ HH:mm:ss');
  var code = Math.floor(Math.random() * 99999) + 10000;

  ws.appendRow([code, d, null, null, formObject.name, formObject.email, 
                  formObject.things]);
  emailCode2(code);
 }

function emailCode2(code){
  var url = "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/11X8e10TGQwzUQVJzTJ24JB1KMCTzkL5F5vObKrH0__k/edit#gid=0";
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(url);
  var lastRow = ss.getLastRow();
  var sheet= ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1");
  
  var name = sheet.getRange(lastRow,5).getValue();
  var emailAddress = sheet.getRange(lastRow,8).getValue();
  var subject = 'Code';

  var message = 'Dear ' + name + ',\n\nHere is your code: ' + code;
  MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subject, message);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this answer?

### Modification points:

- I think that the error means that an error occurs at Google Apps Script side.
- I think that the reason of your issue might be the following part.

  ```
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(url);
    var lastRow = ss.getLastRow();
    var sheet= ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1");
  ```

  In this case, `lastRow` is the 1st tab of the Spreadsheet. If `Sheet1` is not the 1st tab, the last row might be different. Please be careful this. So please modify as follows.

  ```
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(url);
    var sheet= ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1");  // Modified
    var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow();  // Modified
  ```
- If the active Spreadsheet is the same with `var url = "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/11X8e10TGQwzUQVJzTJ24JB1KMCTzkL5F5vObKrH0__k/edit#gid=0";`, after the value was appended with `appendRow`, the email address is retrieved the column "H". But the appended values has the email at the column "F". By this, the email is not declared. By this, an error occurs.

When above points are reflected to your script, it becomes as follows.

### Pattern 1:

If the active Spreadsheet is the same with `var url = "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/11X8e10TGQwzUQVJzTJ24JB1KMCTzkL5F5vObKrH0__k/edit#gid=0";`, how about the following modification?

#### Modified script:

```
function processForm2(formObject) {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var ws = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1");
  var tz = ss.getSpreadsheetTimeZone();
  var d = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), tz, 'dd/MM/yyyy @ HH:mm:ss');
  var code = Math.floor(Math.random() * 99999) + 10000;

  ws.appendRow([code, d, null, null, formObject.name, formObject.email, formObject.things]);
  emailCode2(code);
}

function emailCode2(code){
  var url = "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/11X8e10TGQwzUQVJzTJ24JB1KMCTzkL5F5vObKrH0__k/edit#gid=0";
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(url);
  var sheet= ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1");  // Modified
  var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow();  // Modified
  
  var name = sheet.getRange(lastRow,5).getValue();
  var emailAddress = sheet.getRange(lastRow,6).getValue();  // Modified
  var subject = 'Code';

  var message = 'Dear ' + name + ',\n\nHere is your code: ' + code;
  MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subject, message);
}
```

### Pattern 2:

If the active Spreadsheet is NOT the same with `var url = "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/11X8e10TGQwzUQVJzTJ24JB1KMCTzkL5F5vObKrH0__k/edit#gid=0";`, how about the following modification?

#### Modified script:

```
function processForm2(formObject) {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var ws = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1");
  var tz = ss.getSpreadsheetTimeZone();
  var d = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), tz, 'dd/MM/yyyy @ HH:mm:ss');
  var code = Math.floor(Math.random() * 99999) + 10000;

  ws.appendRow([code, d, null, null, formObject.name, formObject.email, formObject.things]);
  emailCode2(code);
}

function emailCode2(code){
  var url = "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/11X8e10TGQwzUQVJzTJ24JB1KMCTzkL5F5vObKrH0__k/edit#gid=0";
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(url);
  var sheet= ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1");  // Modified
  var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow();  // Modified
  
  var name = sheet.getRange(lastRow,5).getValue();
  var emailAddress = sheet.getRange(lastRow,8).getValue();
  var subject = 'Code';

  var message = 'Dear ' + name + ',\n\nHere is your code: ' + code;
  MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subject, message);
}
```

### Note:

- In this modification, it supposes that `formObject` of `processForm2(formObject)` has the correct values. If this has wrong values, an error might occur. Please be careful this.

### Reference:

- [getLastRow()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getlastrow)

Comment: Ohh I see.. Yeah its not in the 1st tab, I modified the lastRow and now it works well! Thank you for your clear explaination!